# Any hosting provider with scalability, unix, MySQL, managed server?

Tags: scalability, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I work for a company that runs several websites, most of them made with CakePHP (so lots of PHP and SQL). They are currently in a 1&1 shared unix hosting, and we're looking to move somewhere else.

We're looking for a solution that obviously allows us to move all those websites and create similar ones (so with PHP, MySQL database, unix...). We would like it to be easily scalable in terms of computing power, since right now we don't have a lot of users navigating the websites at the same time, but that could dramatically change during this year.

We don't have experience managing/maintaining servers, so we would need some sort of managed service (like a managed dedicated server maybe?).

We've been looking to Amazon's EC2, but it looks a little bit overkill for us, and since they don't provide any kind of managing service, it requires for us to hire some other company to do that, which for what I've seen so far increases the cost a lot.

Any advice on this topic would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rackspace provides managed hosting - http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any experience managing servers, you should go with a regular web hosting.

If you want a scalable one, you can use [Gandi Simple Hosting](https://www.gandi.net/hosting/simple) for example or [Pagoda Box](http://www.newpagodabox.com/)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "regular". What we have now I would say is regular, but we need something else. I believe that if we get a managed hosting we wouldn't have to worry about managing or maintaining the server right?

Comment: @Albert "regular" wasn't the good word...what I meant was that if you don't know how to manage a server, you should probably go with a 'shared hosting' rather than with a 'managed hosting'. In the second one, you don't have to worry about the hardware part, but what's running on it still depends on you.

Comment: ok thank you for the clarification. There are companies offering managed cloud hostings (like rackspace, thanks to the other response's link), which are very flexible and you don't need to worry at all about the server